# Jsoup - Select the value from href attribute

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

The html code (not from my website, so I cant change it) looks like this:

```
<div id="resulttable"> 
 <div class="dirlist"> 
  <div class="stationcol" style="width:428px;"> 
   <a href="http://whatever.com?id=xxx" title="Whatever" class="playbutton playimage" name="whatever" id="105867"></a> 
   <div class="videoBody"> 
    <div class="gridModule"> 
     <div class="surrogate"> 
      <div id="thumbnail105867" class="thumbnail"> 
       <a class="playbutton clickabletitle" name="whatever" id="105867" title="Whatever" href="http://whatever.com?id=xxx"> Bla </a>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Here is my Code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(result);
Elements hrefs = doc.select("div.stationcol a[href]");
StringBuilder links = new StringBuilder();

for (Element href : hrefs) {
    links.append(href.text());
}

String httplinks = links.toString();
System.out.println("TEST: " + httplinks);
```

The output looks like:

```
I/System.out(10451): Link1http://www.whatever.c...Link2http://www.test.c...
```

What I really need is an `ArrayList` that contains the Urls and maybe one separate `ArrayList` that contains the Titles.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(result);
Elements links = doc.select("div.stationcol > a[href]");

for (Element e : links) {
    titles.add(e.attr("title"));
    urls.add(e.attr("href"));
}

System.out.println(titles);
System.out.println(urls);
```

This will output the contents of both ArrayLists in your sample code, e.g:

```
[Whatever]
[http://whatever.com?id=xxx]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works perfectly and it is excactly what i meant! you are the best :-)